# Partitions and a file layout, are partitions preserved in a file layout when written?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm using a custom `partitioner` to partition my `RDD` and then I just save it using `saveAsTextFile`. Is a partition's ordering always guaranteed when saved? In particular: ordering itself and 1 partition to 1 file match? So it will look like this:

```
part-00000 - 1 partition
part-00001 - 2 partition even if it's empty
part-00002 - 3 partition
...
```

Or it may vary?

I'm using Spark 1.6